# Ajax: conflict in client between two functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

For a university homework, I have to create a little e-commerce website.
After the login, the user is redirected to the homepage. In this homepage, the client will recive a JSON object from the server (containing some product to be loaded) to generate the DOM of the homepage dynamically.

Note: I must use AJAX and JSON

I have this client.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // AJAX request on submit
    $("#login_form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: {
                Email: document.getElementById('login_email').value, // Email in the form
                Password: document.getElementById('login_password').value // // Password in the form
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                window.location.href = "home.php"; // load the home.php page in the default folder
            }
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    // AJAX request to open a channel between php and client
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "queries.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data); // debug
                showProducts(data);
            });
        });
    });
});

function showProducts(data){
    alert(data);
    // Insert object into the page DOM
}
```

I don't know why, but I can't access after the login if the second Ajax request (the AJAX request to open a channel between php and client) is not commented, and I don't know why, because the code seems right... Any suggestion?

Comment: @messerbill [Why not?](https://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready)

Comment: `function (e)`  is syntax error

Comment: @messerbill any reliable sources for that affirmation?

Comment: @messerbill Not really, being able to keep stuff in different files using multiple `$(document).ready()`'s might lead to a few more bytes, but it can greatly improve the overview. You are probably using multiple already if you use any jquery plugins.

Answer (score 0):

after login action you need to set to cookie token in response

```
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
            // then set to cookie response.token
            window.location.href = "home.php";
        }
```

after set token to cookie, you need to send this token to next ajax request  `url: "queries.php",`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your anonymous function in parenthesis and add `()` at the end if you want to execute it:

```
(function (e) {
    // I don't know why you need this:
    e.preventDefault();
    // etc.
})();
```

You should also check the contents of that function as you seem to have too many closing parentheses and you don't need to parse the returned value if you set the dataType to `json`.

In the end I think this is about all you need for that function:

```
(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "queries.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); // debug
            showProducts(data);
        }
    });
})();
```

or just:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "queries.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); // debug
        showProducts(data);
    }
});
```

To get it directly on page load.

Comment: in that anon function, `e` is undefined. I don't think OP meant it to be anonymous

Comment: @Adelin I would guess so, that's why I added that comment. I'm not sure if it is meant to be anonymous or even a function, the OP seems to want to load it automatically on page load.